# Can a PUBG match end in a draw or 2 chicken dinners?

Tags: xbox-one, pubg-battlegrounds

I was playing Player Unknown Battlegrounds a few nights ago and I made it to the top 2 when the circle completely closed.  I couldn't find the remaining player as half the circle landed on a 3 story building. Once the circle completely closed, I immediately started using bandages to try to survive longer than the last person, but I ended up taking 2nd (out of playzone).  This then sparked the question - Can a match end in a tie ?

If we both didn't use bandages and we were both killed at the same time by being out of the playzone, what determines the winner?

*I added the xbox-one tag as I know the PC PUBG is on a different version, but unsure of the differences.*

Comment: Are trades where both combatants kill each other ever possible?

Comment: @RoijanEskor I have traded with players at long distances before - sniping - but we weren't the last two

Comment: Regarding situations where both players may die simultaneously: Both players die to the same tick of out of play zone damage, Both players die to the same Frag Grenade, Both players die to a crash while being in the same vehicle, etc.It is definitely possible to have simultaneous deaths, its just difficult to test these things since it is so hard to get a custom server.

Answer (score 6):

**No, it is not possible for a PUBG Match to end in a draw or have two teams as Winners.**

This was recently tested, with the results posted on YouTube here:

At least in the case where both people die to the same grenade, the player who committed suicide will not win the game, whereas the other player who died will win.

The Video does not test what would happen if both players are killed simultaneously by a (dead) third party, however the results of the test suggest that it just isn't possible to draw the game at all.

Comment: I suppose the player who had thrown the grenade(one who committed suicide) will win the game and not the other guy.

Answer (score 3):

Draw (or 2 chicken dinners) is impossible.

There will be always a difference of milliseconds in the death of two parties other than: one grenade killing both of them at the same time: In this case, The party who had thrown the grenade will win.

I've done this many times when only a bot is left alive.

Source:

Comment: Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N63heD_w2R8&t=440s

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe that is possible. In the end, one will most likely die before the other one.
If somehow you both die at the exact same millisecond, they still will choose one as the winner (its happened to me before).

Comment: Do you have any sources to support this or is it just a guess from your experience?

Comment: Sorry for answering so late, and the first part I am pretty sure they said in a blog somewhere... however dying in the same millisecond is just a guess based on my experience as I played a round in squads where my teammate and the other squad died at the exact same time, yet they won... could have been because they boosted but I am not sure.

Answer (score -2):

Nope, it is impossible to end in a draw.
As @Poker1st mentioned, dying in the same millisecond is impossible.
Also if that does happen, tiebreaker will be decided just like in Sports, say based on rating or higher kills.
But PUBG mobile is not open source and it is impossible to verify this through code, so unless someone wasted a room card to find out, we will never know.